# Dask DataFrame: apply custom function to the entire Column, involving min(), max()

Tags: python, dask

A huge dataset with 100M records and 60K columns loaded into a Dask dataframe. Need to perform min() & max() on the entire column. Using Pandas is ruled out due to memory issues.

```
#Sample Dask Dataframe
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                    'col2': [2., 3., 4., 5., 6.],
                    'col3': [4, 6, 8, 3, 2],
                     .
                     .
                     .
                    'col60000':[3,4,5,6,7]
                  })
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=30)
```

I could not use map_partitions function as it applies to the corresponding partition and not on the entire column

```
min_deviation = lambda x: (x - x.min())

for col in ddf.columns:
    print("processing column:", col)
    res = ddf[col].map_partitions(min_deviation).compute()
    print(res)
```

```
Results:
processing column: col1
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    0
4    1
Name: col1, dtype: int64
processing column: col2
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    0.0
4    1.0
Name: col2, dtype: float64
processing column: col3
0    0
1    2
2    4
3    1
4    0
Name: col3, dtype: int64
```

Also Dask apply() function is not supported on columnwise operation.

Is there any other way around to perform the entire columnwise operation with Dask dataframe.

Comment: I don't understand why the output for `[1,2,3,4,5]` is not `[0,1,2,3,4]`. Do you mind to explain?

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: @rpanai The computation is applied only to the rows within each partition. here row index - 0,1,2 belong to a partition and 3,4 to another partition. So, min() is applied only to the rows within that partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dask dataframe has [`max`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.max) and `min` method that work column-wise by default, and produce results from the whole data, all partitions. You can also use these results in further arithmetic with or without computing them to concrete values

- `df.min().compute()` - the concrete minima of each column
- `(df - df.min())` - lazy version of what you said
- `(df - df.min().compute())` - compute the minima up front (may be useful, depending on what you plan to do next)

Comment: Thanks. `(df.compute() - df.min().compute())` - Upfront computation worked with this.

Comment: In this case you are materialising the whole dataframe. If this works, good for you, but you probably didn't need dask's out-of-core processing in the first place.